# 0 is not in range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to load my data from jupyter into mysql workbench using the one "multiple row" insert statement. I will achieve that with a for loop and i am receiving some error messages.

First, a little background:

So I had my csv file which contains data set for preprocessing and I split into 2 here:

```
Before_handwashing=copy_monthly_df.iloc[:76] 
After_handwashig=copy_monthly_df.iloc[76:]
```

I have successfully structured and loaded the first data set Before_handwashing into mysql work bench using this for loop below.

```
for x in range(Before_handwashing.shape[0]):
    insert_query+='('
    for y in range(Before_handwashing.shape[1]):
        insert_query+= str(Before_handwashing[Before_handwashing.columns.values[y]][x])+', '
    insert_query=insert_query[:-2]+'), '
```

Now I want to structure and load my second part of the dataset which is After_handwashig into mysql workbench using a similar code structure here.

```
for x in range(After_handwashig.shape[0]):
    insert_query+='('
    for y in range(After_handwashig.shape[1]):
        insert_query+=str(After_handwashig[After_handwashig.columns.values[y]][x])+', '
    insert_query=insert_query[:-2]+'), '
```

And I am recieving the following error messages

```
error message: ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    384                 try:
--> 385                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    386                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 0 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4316/2677185951.py in <module>
      2     insert_query+='('
      3     for y in range(After_handwashig.shape[1]):
----> 4         insert_query+=str(After_handwashig[After_handwashig.columns.values[y]][x])+', '
      5     insert_query=insert_query[:-2]+'), '

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
_get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)    
   1053 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    385                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    386                 except ValueError as err:
--> 387                     raise KeyError(key) from err
    388             raise KeyError(key)
    389         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

KeyError: 0
```

Can someone help me out in answering this problem?

Comment: Try to post a [mre], which reproduces your problem. that way you do not have to post so much error messages, and someone can test to see what is happening, because no one (except you) know what `After_handwashig` does do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am new here so still trying to find my way around posting questions with code here. Will repost again using your guide

Comment: You can use [edit] to change this question, no need to leave this question here.....

Comment: Alright I have done, I hope I was able to help people answer my question

Comment: What the error says is that `After_handwashig` either has no columns or no rows.  That's not a very satisfying answer, because in that case the `for` loops should not have run.  Have you printed `After_handwashig.shape` and `After_handwashig.columns.values` just to double check?

Comment: Yes, I have After_handwashig.shape returns an output (22,5) ie 22 rows and 5 columns. After_handwashig.columns.values returns my column names @TimRoberts

Answer (score 2):

OK, it took me a moment to find this.  Consider these statements:

```
Before_handwashing=copy_monthly_df.iloc[:76] 
After_handwashig=copy_monthly_df.iloc[76:]
```

When these are done, `Before` contains lines with indexes 0 to 75.  `After` contains lines starting with index 76.  There is no line with index 0, so your attempt to access it causes a key error.

There are two solutions.  One is to use `iloc` to reference lines by ordinal instead of by index:

```
        insert_query+=str(After_handwashig[After_handwashig.columns.values[y]]./iloc(x))+', '
```

The other is to reset the indexes to start from 0:

```
After_handwashing.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

There's really no point in splitting the dataframe like that.  Just have your first loop do `range(76):` and the second do `range(76,copy_monthly_dy.shape[1]):`.

Comment: wow! ok, let me try these solutions. I will comment on feedback. Thank you!

Comment: So I carried out the index reset and it sort of fixed the problem but now my reverse indexing: insert_query=insert_query[:-2]+'), ' now delivers an error message saying invalid syntax

Comment: Never mind, it worked perfectly. The invalid syntax was because I missed a parenthesis. Thank you so much for your helpful response!